# Получить 10 случайных элементов из таблицы в базе данных, используя Linq. ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

Я хочу вывести на страничку 10 случайных элементов из БД. Вот логика хранилища:

```
public class LanguagesRapository
{
    private Context context;
    public LanguagesRapository()
    {
        context = new Context(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString);
    }
    public IEnumerable<English> GetEnglishWords()
    {           

        return context.EnglishWords;
    }
    public English GetEnglishWordsByID(int id)
    {
        return context.EnglishWords.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id);
    }
    public IEnumerable<English> GetRandom10EnglishWords()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();

        return context.EnglishWords.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).Take(10);
    }       
}
```

Получил такую ошибку:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Next()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Попробовал малость изменить  на :

```
public IEnumerable<English> GetRandom10EnglishWords()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();

    return context.EnglishWords.OrderBy(x => int.Parse( rnd.Next().ToString()) == x.ID).Take(10);
}
```

Все равно такая ошибка. Подскажите как правильно получить рандомные данные из БД.

Вот код View:

```html
@using VocabularyDomain.Enitities
@model IEnumerable<English>

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @foreach (English eng in Model)
        {
            <div>@eng.translation    @eng.word </div>
        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Может кому нужно будет. Решил проблему таким способом.

```
public IEnumerable<English> GetRandom10EnglishWords()
{
    return context.EnglishWords.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Когда Вы пишете LINQ-выражение при использовании различных ORM вроде LINQ to Entities или EntityFramework, имейте ввиду, что написанное Вами выражение `context.EnglishWords.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).Take(10)` будет преобразовано этими библиотеками в SQL запрос, который затем будет выполнен в БД.

При формировании SQL запроса происходит разбор дерева выражений (в описанном случае разбор выражения `x => rnd.Next()`). Обратите внимание, что все LINQ методы принимают не `Func<TEntry, TResult>`, а `Expression<Func<TEntry, TResult>>`.

Далее производится обход дерева выражений, и каждый вызов метода преобразуется в вызов соответствующей функции SQL. После чего результирующий SQL выполняется, а результаты запроса ORM преобразует в экземпляры соответствующих классов. Нужно понимать, что фактического вызова метода `Random.Next()` на стороне C# кода не произойдет, и уж тем более не зачем использовать экземпляр .NET объекта внутри LINQ-выражения в контексте обращения к БД. Как этот экземпляр объекта может быть использован на стороне сервера БД?

Почему сработал `Guid.NewGuid()`, но не заработал `Random.Next()`? Для метода `Guid.NewGuid()` очевидно мапинг на SQL функцию существует. Для MS SQL Server, например, `Guid.NewGuid()` может соответствовать вызову SQL функции `NEWID()`. А для метода `Random.Next()` такой мапинг скорее всего отсутствует.

Пример как сделать такой мапинг можно найти [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb386973(v=vs.110).aspx).